# Android ListView shows only last item

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on project with listview,but I have a little problem. I'm using SimpleAdapter so I can change the view of my listview,but it shows only the last element.Here is the code :

```
private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> items;
    private final String TIME = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plovdiv);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ListView schedule = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pld_schedule);
        items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        hm.put(TIME, "06:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "06:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "07:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "07:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "08:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "09:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "10:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "10:45");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "11:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "12:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "13:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "13:45");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "14:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "15:15");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "16:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "16:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "17:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "17:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "18:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "18:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "19:30");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "20:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "20:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "21:40");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME, "22:30");
        items.add(hm);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
                new String[]{TIME}, new int[]{ R.id.text});

        schedule.setAdapter(adapter);
        schedule.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
```

Here is plovdiv.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <DigitalClock 
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/pld_schedule"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clock"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is main_listview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As a result I get a listview with only the last item added : `22:30`.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep overwriting your hashmap every time you add it, you need to make a new hashmap for each entry:

```
{
    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put(TIME, "06:00");
    items.add(hm);
}
{
    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put(TIME, "06:30");
    items.add(hm);
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

your TIME variable is constant, so your hashMap will finally have only 1 item at the end of adding all items. so i suggest you to keep changing the TIME variable, for every item you add.

```
hm.put(TIME + "time1", "06:00");
        items.add(hm);

        hm.put(TIME + "time2", "06:30");
        items.add(hm);
```

use something like given above, you should change the key value.

Comment: I changed TIME to only string and still have only the last item.Actually I used that code before but in for statement and had no problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use the same key for every entry in your hashmap..

[take a look at HashMap put java doc here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)